# Why i feel cold

Tags: nutrition, medications, mental-health, thyroid

I would like to ask you if you know the reasons somebody feels
Cold .I have underthyroid  problem.Is there connection between the cold and the underthyroid?My age is 25 and i am woman

Comment: Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here, to avoid closure, please try to edit the question so that it is generic. Nobody here can properly address your health issues. Such questions should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and access your full medical records. For more information, please see this [meta post](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here/258).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may be cold for several reasons:  **low air temperature** especially if it is windy and humid, is the most common cause. Some people are cold at 70ºF, others only at 60ºf and a few people are very hardy and can easily tolerate temperatures below 50ºF provided there is no wind.

Younger and physically active people can also tolerate low temperatures better than **the aged or bedridden**.

High body temperature is another cause: **fever and hyperthermia** are examples.

Some **disease states** also make you more sensitive to cold temperatures: **hypothyroidism** is one of them.